# javascript recurrence calculator for repeating iCal event (RFC 2445)

Tags: javascript, calendar

At the moment, I've been making ajax calls to [the PHP library iCalCreator](http://kigkonsult.se/iCalcreator/index.php) to handle iCal events with recurrences. There's a function `_recur2date` in that, that calculates the next recurrence of an event, based on a given start date and an iCal RRULE (RFC 2445).

Is there a javascript library that will do the same: that is, given an RFC-2445 compliant recurrence rule, and a start date, will calculate the next recurrence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been playing around a bit with iCal processing the last month or so (as a side side project) in both PHP & JS. I haven't *yet* used the js option I found **very much**; however so far it has seemed good enough to recommend.

[rrule.js](https://github.com/jkbr/rrule)

It requires underscore.js and supports using nlp.js to do natural language processing of dates as well.

I don't believe there is a built in next however that is easy to do; I suspect you will want to do something like this:

```
function get_next(rulestring) {
    var rule = RRule.fromString(rulestring);
    return rule.all(function (date, i){return i < 1});
}
console.log(get_next("FREQ=WEEKLY;DTSTART=20120201T093000Z")); //any valid RFC2445 string.
```